# Disable archiving support in org-mode in emacs

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I am hitting the wrong key by mistake in Emacs all the time. This is archiving some parts of my `org-mode` tree (and Emacs' undo system, combined with `org-mode`'s partial view of the tree, makes understanding what happened, or fixing it, extremely hard).

How can I find and disable all key bindings related to archiving, completely?

Comment: You may wish to consider adding a confirmation yes/no, instead of disabling it completely.  Here is an example of setting a few key-bindings to a `nil` value:  https://superuser.com/questions/828713/how-to-override-a-keybinding-in-emacs-org-mode/828744#828744  See also:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7546/disable-org-mode-keyboard-shortcuts  The latter uses `eval-after-load` which will save time on Emacs startup, whereas you lose a split-second or or so if you `require` the library at startup.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I discover all interactive functions that have to do with archiving, with key bindings?

Comment: `M-x find-library RET org-archive RET`.  Then, isearch for the word `interactive` and you will find approximately four (4) functions depending upon your version of `org-mode`.  Make a mental note, or a written note, of those functions and then `grep` the `org` source directory for those functions.  I see three defined with `org-defkey` and I see one of those special single letter keys for when a user is at the beginning of a heading (speed-dial keys or something like that) with the letter "a" defined to one of those commands.  Again, your org-version may have some differences than what I see.

Comment: That's very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find commands, `C-h a` (apropos-command) is often helpful. It will ask you for a regex and will return all commands that match the regex. So if you type the following: `C-h a ^org-.*archive`
you will get a list of commands starting with "org-" and containing the word "archive".

That said, checking the source as @lawlist suggests is of course better as commands are not always named the way one expects, though you here need to sift through not just the commands (ie those that can be bound to key combinations) but also all of the helper functions.

Other ways to quickly get to source files is, if you know of a specific command, to type `C-h k` and the key combination. This will bring up the help for that function, and from there you will normally find a button that brings you to the source file contains that command (provided emacs knows where it is).

There is a sister command to 'command-apropos' which is just named 'apropos'. This will search among all commands, functions and variables.